# Getting daily first in last out times for each employee in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for asking yet another attendance based question, but none of the other solutions here quite seem to work for me.

I need to get list of 'first in last out' for each employee every day. Table looks something like this:

```
id  date_time               access  emp_id
1   2016-01-01T09:00:00Z    In      00101
2   2016-01-01T09:10:00Z    In      00302
3   2016-01-01T13:10:00Z    Out     00101
4   2016-01-01T13:05:00Z    Out     00302
5   2016-01-01T14:00:00Z    In      00302
6   2016-01-01T14:10:00Z    In      00101
7   2016-01-01T17:00:00Z    Out     00101
8   2016-01-01T17:10:00Z    Out     00302
9   2016-01-02T09:05:00Z    In      00101
10  2016-01-02T09:10:00Z    In      00302
11  2016-01-02T12:05:00Z    Out     00101
12  2016-01-02T12:35:00Z    Out     00302
13  2016-01-02T13:40:00Z    In      00302
14  2016-01-02T17:15:00Z    Out     00302
15  2016-01-03T08:50:00Z    In      00302
16  2016-01-03T17:10:00Z    Out     00101
```

I need a result that comes out like this:

```
workday     emp_id  entry_time              entry_time
2016-01-01  00101   2016-01-01T09:00:00Z    2016-01-01T17:00:00Z
2016-01-01  00302   2016-01-01T09:10:00Z    2016-01-01T17:10:00Z
2016-01-02  00101   2016-01-02T09:05:00Z    2016-01-02T12:05:00Z
2016-01-02  00302   2016-01-02T09:10:00Z    2016-01-02T17:15:00Z
2016-01-03  00302   2016-01-03T08:50:00Z    0
2016-01-03  00101   0                       2016-01-03T17:10:00Z
```

So on day 2, I know that 1 employee left for lunch and didn't come back. While on day 3, some employees have been tail-gating and need to be lectured on pass usage.

My problem is that it isn't so simple as to just get min/max times as they are based off the access type. Its not difficult to get the entry or exit times separately but combining them into 1 result table is tricky due to the lack of a full outer join in MYSQL.

```
select cast(date_time as date) as workday, emp_id, min(date_time) as entry_time from attendance where access = 'In' group by date(date_time), emp_id order by workday;
select cast(date_time as date) as workday, emp_id, max(date_time) as exit_time from attendance where access = 'Out' group by date(date_time), emp_id order by workday;
```

Do excuse me if I do not also provide my rather sorry attempts at trying out left/right join on those statements.

Best I can manage puts the entry and exit times on separate rows and that isn't ideal.

```
select cast(date_time as date) as workday, emp_id, IF (access = 'In', MIN(date_time), 0) as entry_time, IF (access = 'Out', MAX(date_time), 0) as exit_time from attendance group by date(date_time), emp_id, access order by workday;
```

Produces:

```
workday     emp_id  entry_time          exit_time
2016-01-01  00101   2016-01-01 09:00:00 0
2016-01-01  00101   0                   2016-01-01 17:00:00
2016-01-01  00302   2016-01-01 09:10:00 0
2016-01-01  00302   0                   2016-01-01 17:10:00
2016-01-02  00101   2016-01-02 09:05:00 0
2016-01-02  00101   0                   2016-01-02 12:05:00
2016-01-02  00302   2016-01-02 09:10:00 0
2016-01-02  00302   0                   2016-01-02 17:15:00
2016-01-03  00101   0                   2016-01-03 17:10:00
2016-01-03  00302   2016-01-03 08:50:00 0
```

[What I have tried on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/009624/7)

Is there something that I have missed? Is there a better way of doing things?

Any assistance is appreciated, thank you kindly in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do another `group by`. See below:

```
select p.workday, p.emp_id, max(p.time_in), max(p.time_out)
from (
      select cast(date_time as date) as workday, emp_id, 
            min(case when (access='In') then date_time else 0 end) as time_in, 
            max(case when (access='Out') then date_time else 0 end) as time_out
      from attendance
      group by cast(date_time as date), emp_id, access
  ) as p
  group by p.workday, p.emp_id
```

This will produce your expected result. Here is a [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9fd798/12)

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a shot on my actual database.

Comment: @noobcakes . . . You should accept this answer, if it works for ou.